# A* Search but we don't know the heuristics for all states

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I'm trying to do a project about A* search (Finding a path between source and target where each block can be a path with cost 4, a brick with cost 10 or a hole with cost 50 ) but it's different in a way that you don't have the heuristics for all states initially and you can calculate the heuristic only for the state you are in. My first thought was to visit all the adjacent blocks and store the heuristics and come back to the previous block in order to find all heuristics and calculate f and decide which node to expand but that would be a big waste of cost as you would lose at least 4 scores for visiting each node. My TA said there is a better way of doing this but I can't figure out how it might be possible not to calculate all the heuristic values as the one we are not calculating may be the one that is actually more efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by “can only calculate the heuristic for the state you’re in?” Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @templatetypedef We have several functions for going in different directions (goUp, goDown, goLeft, goRight) and for checking the type of adjacent blocks (for example WhatsRight will tell you if there is a brick to your right) but the only function we have regarding heuristic returns the heuristic of the block you are already in and not the adjacent ones.

Comment: Do the goUp / goDown functions undo each other? If so, couldn’t you goUp, evaluate the heuristic there, then goDown to return to where you were?

Comment: @templatetypedef that’s exactly what I said my first thought was but they don’t cancel each other and you would lose a lot of score

Comment: Can you provide additional context about what this score is? More generally, where are these functions from? Is this for a class project?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, the functions are coded and given to us and we can only use them. The goal is to find the path from source to target with the highest score possible.